# Cannot ping Vagrant guest machine for particular versions of guest

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox, centos7

I'm trying to work through Chef tutorials on my MacBook Pro (running OS X 10.10.5), and I've come across a problem.

Here's a `Vagrantfile` that I distilled from one in the tutorial:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

NODE_SCRIPT = <<EOF.freeze
echo "Preparing node..."

EOF

def set_hostname(server)
  server.vm.provision 'shell', inline: "hostname #{server.vm.hostname}"
end

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define 'node1-centos' do |n|
    n.vm.box = 'bento/centos-7.2'
    n.vm.hostname = 'node1-centos'
    n.vm.network 'private_network', ip: '10.1.1.34'
    n.vm.provision :shell, inline: NODE_SCRIPT.dup
    set_hostname(n)
  end
end
```

After I run `vagrant up`, I try `ping 10.1.1.34`, but get no responses.  I do see the private network when I run `netstat -rn`.

However, if I change the line

```
n.vm.box = 'bento/centos-7.2'
```

to

```
n.vm.box = 'bento/centos-6.7'
```

then `ping` is successful.

I also tried it on my Ubuntu 16.04 box, with the same problem.

Is there a way to resolve this?  I need Centos 7 for testing.  (I tried Centos 7.1 and had the same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a bug in Vagrant 1.9.1.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553621/) to the post "Centos7 with private network lost fixed IP".